# sprite image leaving a shadow/tail while moving on screen

Tags: android, game-engine

My android game program has sprites moving on the screen, but they are leaving a trace/tail/shadow behind. I have tried different FPS unsuccessfully also tried canvas.drawARGB(100,0,0,0); which other thread suggested, it removes the tail but dims other sprites. Here'e the code

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        gameloopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                createSprites();
                gameloopThread.setRunning(true);
                gameloopThread.start();
                }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                boolean retry = true;
                gameloopThread.setRunning(false);
                while (retry) {
                       try {
                             gameloopThread.join();
                             retry = false;
                       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       }
                }
            }
        }); 


    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawColor(color.black);
        for (int i = temps.size() -1; i>=0; i--) {
            temps.get(i).onDraw(canvas);
        }
        for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
        //  canvas.drawARGB(8,8,8,8);  // mine
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Heres the class for game loop

```
public class GameLoopThread extends Thread {
    static final long FPS = 10;  

    @Override
    public void run(){
        long ticksPS = 1000/FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;
        while (running) {
            Canvas c = null;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                  c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                  synchronized (view.getHolder())
                  {

                      view.onDraw(c);
                  }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
            sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
            try {
                  if (sleepTime > 0)
                         sleep(sleepTime);
                  else
                      sleep(10); // sleep causes it to change speed and jerk, hi sleep hi jerk
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

    }
```

and the sprite class ....

```
public class Sprite {

     private GameView gameView;


    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        update();
        int srcX = currentFrame * width;
        int srcY = getAnimationRow() * height;
        Rect src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX+width, srcY + height);
        Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, src, dst, null);
    }
    // direction = 0 up, 1 left, 2 down, 3 right
    // animation = 3 back, 1 left, 0 front, 2 right
    private int getAnimationRow() {

        return DIRECTION_TO_ANIMATION_MAP[direction];
    }

}
```

I can't find any method to recreate canvas after sprite change position. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the frequency at which you call the onDraw() method. You need to increase the frames per second by either changing the value passed to the constant `FPS` in `static final long FPS = 10;` or to `long ticksPS = 1000/FPS;`

The side effect of increasing this value is that it will take more processor power and  your bitmaps will move faster and to reduce their speed, you need to change the rate at which x and y change in `Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);`

Comment: changed FPS, didn't help, i think its related to sleeptime but different processor will need different sleep before redraw, depending upon speed?

Answer (score 0):

just add  canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
or any color
i encountered the same problem and that code save my me